# Tell completion for a set of celery tasks

Tags: python, celery, django-celery, celery-task

How I can run a another method **action()** automatically when a set of celery tasks is finished. Are there any simple way to trigger another function call on completion?

```
#tasks.py
@app.task
def rank(item):
   # Update database
```

```
#main.py
from tasks import rank
def action():
   print('Tasks has been finished.')
ans = list()
for item in tqdm.tqdm(all_items):

        rank.apply_async(([{"_id": item["_id"], "max": item["max"]}]))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Celery workers return results to the main program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72739893/celery-workers-return-results-to-the-main-program)

Comment: chord(header)(callback), I am not sure why the callback has to be a celery@app.task

Comment: As shown in my example, the action function is not a celery@app.task but a global function

Comment: I explained how to do it _without_ using Chord as well. Did you read it entirely?

Answer (score 1):

In the previous message that is very similar to this one, which you deleted, I explained how to do this without using the Chord workflow primitive that you for some reason decided to avoid... You even left some parts of that code here that does nothing (`ans = list()`). I will put that part of the answer here, as it explains *how* what you need can be accomplished:

> Without some code changes your code will not work. For starters, apply_async() does not return result. So, after you modify the code to ans.append(rank.apply_async(([{"_id": item["_id"], "max": item["max"]}])).get()) it should work as you want, but unfortunately it will not distribute tasks (which is why we use Celery!), so in order to emulate the logic that Chord does, you would need to call apply_async() as you do, store the task IDs, and periodically poll for state. If the task is finished, get the result and do this until all are finished.

Solution B would be to use Group primitive, schedule your tasks to be executed in a group, obtain GroupResult object, and do the same what I wrote above - periodically poll for individual results.

If you do this polling in a loop, than you can simply call `action()` after the loop, as it will be called after all tasks are finished. Once you implement this you will understand why many of experienced Celery users use Chord instead...

Comment: Thanks a lot. This post also explains how to use group/chord for beginners: https://sayari3.com/articles/18-chains-groups-and-chords-in-celery/